# Data structure for dictionary app in WP

Tags: data-structures, dictionary, data-dictionary

I'm creating a dictionary app for WP.
One of its features is the real-time lookup. While the use is inputing a word, the dictionary will automatically find the recommended-result that is close to what user inputed.
And when the user input "bility", the dictionary must find "reusability", "ability" as the recommened-result.
MY QUESTION IS: what data structures fits my need?

Hashtable and tree structure isn't possible in this case because hashtable can only perform the lookup when the word is fully inputed, and tree structure can just find something close to  "userinputed*" ( assumed the user input "n", the dictionary using tree structure can just find "nice" or "night" but can't find "and" or "ten" )

inputed data sample : recommended-result sample

"bility" => "reuseability"; "responsibility"...

"n" => "and"; "ten"; "nice"; "night"

Answer (score 0):

A suffix trie can find the longest common substring in a string.